# Getting string input, trying to assign it to a variable after / Python

Tags: python, string, variables, input

so I have this small task here, where I have to get user input, based on said input assign different values to variables and then print out the sum of it. If I go by doing 'if' within 'if' it would work, but that would be so much text to begin with. I'm trying to find a way to read user input and match it with a certain value. Maybe that's got something to do with data structures but I'm not that far into it yet. Any suggestions?
Here's the code:

```
input1 = input()
day = input()
quantity = float(input())

if input1 not in ["banana", "apple", "orange", "grapefruit", "kiwi", "pineapple", "grapes"]:
    print("error")
if day in ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]:
    banana = 2.50
    apple = 1.20
    orange = 0.85
    grapefruit = 1.45
    kiwi = 2.70
    pineapple = 5.50
    grapes = 3.85
elif day in ["Saturday", "Sunday"]:
    banana = 2.70
    apple = 1.25
    orange = 0.90
    grapefruit = 1.60
    kiwi = 3
    pineapple = 5.60
    grapes = 4.20
else:
    print("error")

price = input1 * quantity
print(f"{price}:.2f")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) In short, use a dict instead of variables. As a bonus, you can do `if input1 not in d:` to check if it's invalid.

Comment: like {'banana' : [price week , price week-end] ,  ..........}

Comment: input1 = input()
week = input()
how = input()
col = int
dict ={'banana' : [1 , 2]}
if week == 'a':
    col = 0
if week == 'b':
    col = 1
print(int(dict[input1][col])*int(how))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I would use a dictionary to handle this situation, and also exceptions to handle the cases where the fruit names/day names do not match what is expected. For example:

```py
weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
weekends = ['Saturday', 'Sunday']

fruit_prices = {
    'banana': {'weekday': 2.5, 'weekend': 2.5},
    'apple': {'weekday': 1.2, 'weekend': 1.25},
    # ...rest
}

def get_price(fruit, day, quantity):
    if fruit not in fruit_prices:
        raise ValueError(f'no such fruit: {fruit}')
    if day not in weekdays and day not in weekends:
        raise ValueError(f'no such day: {day}')

    price = fruit_prices[fruit]['weekday' if day in weekdays else 'weekend']
    return price * quantity

_fruit = input().strip()
_day = input().strip()
_quantity = float(input().strip())

try:
    print(get_price(_fruit, _day, _quantity))
except ValueError as err:
    print(f'error: {str(err)}')
```